# With 2 as smallest period of the function $f(x)$= $\tan^2[(\frac{\pi x}{n^2-5n+8})]$ + $\cot(n+m)\pi x$ ;the period m can't belong to is?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, periodic-functions

Here n $ \in N$ , m $\in Q$.  
Options are:
A) $(-\infty, -2) \cup (-1, \infty)$  
B) $(-\infty, -3) \cup (-2, \infty)$
C) $(-2,-1) \cup (-3,-2)$
D) $(-3, -5/2) \cup (-5/2, -2)$

---

I have an answer to this question in my book but I don't understand it.
 It is:

Period is LCM of $n^2-5n+8$ and $\frac{1}{n+m}$ .  
 Since $n\in N$
 solving  $n^2 -5n +8=2$ and $n^2 -5n +8=1$ gives $n \in ${2,3}

and $(\frac{1}{n+m})(K) = 2$ ,where K is an integer
$\Rightarrow$ $(\frac{1}{n+m})\ngtr 1 $
$\Rightarrow$ $(\frac{1}{2+m})\ngtr 1 $ or  $(\frac{1}{3+m})\ngtr 1 $ 
$\Rightarrow$ $m \notin (-2,-1) \cup (-3,-2)$

Would anyone please explain how did:
$(\frac{1}{n+m})(K) = 2$$\Rightarrow$   $(\frac{1}{n+m})\ngtr 1 $ happen?

---

If there is any other way then please post it. Thankyou.

Comment: Results for $n$ look correct. From $(\frac{1}{n+m})(K) = 2$ get $m=\frac{K}{2}-n,K\ne0$. For $n=2: m=\ldots,-3,-\frac{5}{2},-\frac{3}{2},-1,-\frac{1}{2},\ldots$ and for $n=3: m=\ldots,-4,-\frac{7}{2},-\frac{5}{2},-2,-\frac{3}{2},\ldots$. So only (D) fits, as $m$ has to be a multiple of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: $n = 2, m = -\frac{3}{2}; f(x) = \tan^2 \frac{\pi x}{2} + \cot \frac{\pi x}{2}$. This has period 2 and $m$ is in the middle of one of your book's solution's proscribed intervals. So that solution is wrong, and you are correct in your complaint.